# How to "set" a selected item in a ListView

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I'm working with ListView controls and have the need to set which item is currently selected, as opposed to getting the current selected item.  I've done a lot of reading and don't seem to be finding how one can do this using code.

Comment: You can find an example in BudgetPlanGenerateFormGenJour.setAccountTypeControlValue, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, Sir Troll you led me to the answer.  It is done by modifying the FormListItem object instead of the ListView itself.  FormListItem.stateSelected(true) will make the item be marked as selected.  I tried marking it selected after it has been added to the ListView and it did not work, it must be done before adding it to the ListView.  However, I haven't tried this, but I suspect it should work if you utilize the ListView.setItem(...) method.

Comment: Can you accept your owner answer as 'solved' so the question will be closed? If not, I'll post my comment as an answer. And indeed the setItem will update the state of the FormListItems in the UI.

Comment: I tried but it says I have to wait 2 days for some reason

Answer (score 2):

You can find an example in BudgetPlanGenerateFormGenJour.setAccountTypeControlValue.

```
FormListItem item;

item = ListView.getItem(1);
item.stateSelected(true) ;
ListView.setItem(item);
```